# Android getExtras/Intent different than expected

Tags: android, android-intent, alarmmanager

In my activity I am managing a list of user supplied food, and I am setting alarms based on when they expire.  However for some reason the intent passed to onRecieve is not the one that I thought it should be.

For example the user enters berries with expiration date 5/8 and butter with expiration 6/4 and then hits save data.  For each item this method is called.  Each time I call this method, I save the expiration date using putExtra with the intent.

```
    public void setOneTimeAlarm(int daysAfterSet) {
    //declare intent using class that will handle alarm
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, FoodExpAlarm.class);
    //retrieve pending intent for broadcast, flag one shot means will only set once
    intent.putExtra("expDate", expDate);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
      intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    //params: specify to use system clock use RTC_WAKEUP to wakeup phone for notification,
    //time to wait, intent
    alarmMan.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
      System.currentTimeMillis() + (daysAfterSet * AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY), pendingIntent);
 }
```

This causes one alarm to be set for berries because they are close to expiration and no alarm for butter (which is a month away from expiration).  The foodExpAlarm class is then called once and a notification for berries is correctly displayed.  However, the problem comes from when the next batch of food is entered.  Next the user enters bacon expiring 5/8 and bananas 5/15.  Now setOneTimeAlarm is called twice again (once for each) and foodExpAlarm is called again once for the bacon.

However, in foodExpAlarm the extras that are passed in are from butter and not bacon.
This makes no sense to me because foodExpAlarm should be called after the time has elapsed, and should be called with the pending intent corresponding to the time scheduled.  However, that does not seem to be the case it seems that the intents (or at very least the extras) only correspond to the order in which all the foods were added.

Execution summary:

- Add berries 5/8
- Add butter 6/4
- Save
- Correctly display berry notification
- Add bacon 5/8
- Add bananas 5/15
- Save
- Incorrectly display butter

My question is, why am I getting the intent/extras for butter and not for bacon? Is my understanding of intents wrong?  How can I fix this?

foodExpAlarm:

```
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Bundle exp = intent.getExtras(); //This gets the extras from butter, not bacon like I want
    Object temp = exp.get("expDate");  
    Enter_Foods.expDate = new DateTime(temp);
    intent.getExtras();
    int id = (int) (Enter_Foods.expDate).getMillis();
    ....

    notificationMan = (NotificationManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    //i think this gets pending intent from the alarm that called this method
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
        new Intent(context,MainActivity.class), Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    //creates notification object/icon, and set text to flow across top bar
    Notification notif = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,
        "Food expiring soon", System.currentTimeMillis());
    //specify what to display when notification is shown
    notif.setLatestEventInfo(context, from, message, contentIntent);
    //use nofication manager to send message to phone, will update if same id
    notificationMan.notify(id, notif);
    }
```

Comment: i think it has to do with Activity.setIntent().   i think you have to override  onNewIntent and update the actitiy to use the new Intent ..

Comment: Does that effect the parameter that is being passed to onRecieve?

Comment: Post the code you use to set the notifications.

Comment: I changed the foodExpAlarm section to show the notification code

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are getting conflicts due to problems with the Alarm manager and intents.  Your intents appear to be the same intent, relative to the intent comparing method used by the Alarm Manager, as they only differ in the "extras" So your alarm's are killing each other.

Here is a quote from [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) for the `AlarmManager.set` method:

> Schedule an alarm. Note: for timing operations (ticks, timeouts, etc)
>   it is easier and much more efficient to use Handler. If there is
>   already an alarm scheduled for the same IntentSender, it will first be
>   canceled.
>
> If the time occurs in the past, the alarm will be triggered
>   immediately. If there is already an alarm for this Intent scheduled
>   (with the equality of two intents being defined by
>   filterEquals(Intent)), then it will be removed and replaced by this
>   one.

And then in the `filterEquals(Intent)` [documentation:](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#filterEquals%28android.content.Intent%29)

> Determine if two intents are the same for the purposes of intent
>   resolution (filtering). That is, if their action, data, type, class,
>   and categories are the same. This does not compare any extra data
>   included in the intents.

Comment: Wouldn't that result in my alarms not triggering at all?  The notifications trigger and the alarms are called like they are supposed to but the extras passed with the notifications are not in the order of the calls to the alarms.  For example the alarm correctly sets for 1 day 3 days 2 days 5 days  but instead of the extras being passed in the chronological order (1 day 2 days 3 days 5 days) it passes the extras in the order the alarms were entered, not in the time when they will go off

Comment: Do you get multiple alarms happening over time?  Do you eventually get all 4 alarms happening?  (I assume you can change the time on your android to get them to happen). In your note, I see two saves with 2 entries that trigger only 2 alarms.

Comment: Yes I will eventually get all of the alarms, the alarms I am referring to in the post that trigger immediately after the foods are entered.  The other alarms don't go off until 6/1 and 5/12 (three days before expiration date).